# How do you pipe an inputstream to a zipped file as it's read in with Java?

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I'm wanting to execute a program and as it runs read in it's output and pipe out the output into a zipped file.  The output of the program can be quite large so the idea is to not hold too much in memory - just to send it to the zip as I get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ZipOutputStream targetStream = new ZipOutputStream(fileToSaveTo);
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(nameOfFileInZipFile);
targetStream.putNextEntry(entry);

byte[] dataBlock = new byte[1024];
int count = inputStream.read(dataBlock, 0, 1024);
while (count != -1) {
    targetStream.write(dataBlock, 0, count);
    count = inputStream.read(dataBlock, 0, 1024);
}
```

In otherwords:

1. You create a `ZipOutputStream`, giving it the file you want to write to.
2. You create a `ZipEntry`, which constitutes a file within that zip file.
   i.e. When you open myFile.zip, and there are 3 files in there, each file is a `ZipEntry`.
3. You put that `ZipEntry` into your `ZipOutputStream`
4. Create a byte buffer to read your data into.
5. Read from your `inputStream` into your byte buffer, and remember the count.
6. While the `count` is not `-1`, write that byte byffer to your `zipStream`.
7. Read the next line.

Close out your streams when you are done. Wrap it in a method as you see fit.