# Stream response from micro-profile REST invocation directly to zip file

Tags: rest, stream, quarkus, microprofile

We potentially have large XML files that we stream from a REST service to a REST client. However, I don't need / want to interpret this files. Instead I want to directly write them to a zip file.

How can I avoid keeping the whole content in memory (e.g. fetching a String)?

My code so far:

```java
    public void process(URL url, ZipOutputStream outputStream) {

        // Build REST client based on subscription URL.
        DispatchService dispatchService = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().baseUrl( url ).build( DispatchService.class );

        try (DispatchService autoCloseableClient = dispatchService) {

            Response response = autoCloseableClient.get( );

            // how shall I write a new entry to the ZIP outputStream by means of the DispatchService?

            LOG.info( "object handled" );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex ) {
            LOG.debug( "an exception occurred while sending the message" );
        }
    }

    @Path( "" )
    public interface DispatchService extends AutoCloseable {

        @POST
        @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML  )
        Response get();
    }
```

I'm always struggling with these constructions, but I could not find a clear example. Questions:

1. Is a `Response` going to work here?
2. I can't find an (output)stream in the response.. So how do I need to do that?
3. Should I for instance use a react (async, Mutany) construction? How would that work if you need to write multiple entries to the same zip (you need to write them one after the other anyway).

Comment: Which REST client extension are you using?

Comment: `<artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive</artifactId>`. I did find a solution: `InputStream inputStream = response.readEntity( InputStream.class )` and then reading blocks in a loop from the inputstream like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137645/how-do-you-pipe-an-inputstream-to-a-zipped-file-as-its-read-in-with-java. Need to test still (ssl problems currently) if this works. And it feels this could be more brief / direct.

Comment: solution works! Still it feels "primitive" to map one stream to another by a while loop.  I'll add the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is described already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137645/how-do-you-pipe-an-inputstream-to-a-zipped-file-as-its-read-in-with-java):

```java
public void process(URL url, ZipOutputStream zipOut) {

        // Build REST client based on subscription URL.
        DispatchService dispatchService = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().baseUrl( url ).build( DispatchService.class );

        try (DispatchService autoCloseableClient = dispatchService) {

            Response response = autoCloseableClient.get( );
            InputStream inputStream = response.readEntity( InputStream.class );

            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry( "somename" );
            zipOut.putNextEntry( zipEntry );
            byte[] dataBlock = new byte[1024];
            int count = inputStream.read(dataBlock, 0, 1024);
            while (count != -1) {
                zipOut.write(dataBlock, 0, count);
                count = inputStream.read(dataBlock, 0, 1024);
            }
            zipOut.closeEntry();

            LOG.info( "object handled" );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex ) {
            LOG.debug( "an exception occurred while sending the message" );
        }
    }

    public interface DispatchService extends AutoCloseable {

        @POST
        @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML  )
        Response get();
    }
```